# iPhone - send a certificate in a request

Tags: ios, request, certificate

Now, I'm planing to send a `NSURLRequest` to the server with a local certificate for server to validate. But I check the function in `NSURLRequest`, I cannot find a way to include the certificate. Does anyone know how to include a certificate in a `NSUrlRequest`? Or must I use a open source function, like `ASIHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give a look to this quite good tutorial

[Authenticating an HTTP Request with Client Certificates in iOS](http://xdumaine.com/2013/02/07/authenticating-an-http-request-with-client-certificates-in-ios/)

It explains how to use the **NSURLConnectionDelegate** method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
 didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

In order to provide the certificate.
Let me know if that helped.

**UPDATE**
In case support just for iOS >= 5.0 is provided, it's better to adopt the new non deprecated method

[connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection%3awillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge%3a)

Comment: can I say [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge] will send a certificate back to the server

Comment: Yes, given that *credential* actually contains all the certificate data:

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity certificates:(NSArray*)certArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

Comment: One more question, this credential will be sent back to the server before receiving data or after that

Comment: Before of course, as even The documentationstates: "Sent when a connection must authenticate a challenge in order to download its request." I noticed that they deprecated that method in favour of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:), so if you are planning to provide support just for iOS >= 5.0, you'd better use the new one.

Comment: yes, i know that, but it also said if the old function still can work if you dont use the new one. thanks :)